# Create SSO Application with MSBuild .Net 4.6.2

Tags: msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-2016

With .Net 3.5, I could able to using MSBuild to create a SSO Apllication (Type: *Config Store*) and read values with *SSOSettingsFileReader.ReadString(appName, keyName)*. The msbuild script is:

```
<Sso.CreateApp ApplicationName="$(SsoAppName)" SettingsFile="@(SettingsGroup)"
               AdminGroup="$(SsoAppAdminGroup)" UserGroup="$(SsoAppUserGroup)" ContactInfo="$(MsiManufacturer)"
               SettingNameWhiteList="$(SsoSettingNameWhiteList)" SettingNameBlackList="$(SsoSettingNameBlackList)"
               Condition="%(Identity) == %(Identity) and Exists(%(fullpath))"/>
```

After upgrading to .Net 4.6.2, I am using the same, the app is created with all keys/values, but I cannot read the Value by Key anymore, by *SSOSettingsFileReader* or by *SSOConfigStore.GetConfigStore*(...).

```
        var ssoStore = new SSOConfigStore();
        var appMgmtBag = new ConfigurationPropertyBag();
        ((ISSOConfigStore) ssoStore).GetConfigInfo(appName, idenifierGUID, SSOFlag.SSO_FLAG_RUNTIME, appMgmtBag);
        object propertyValue;
        appMgmtBag.Read(propName, out propertyValue, 0);
        return (string)propertyValue;
```

The error message is:

```
The mapping does not exist. For Config Store applications, the config info has not been set.
```

If I use SSO Application Configuration, manually create an app with test key/value. I can retrieve the value.

Please tell me how can I create a SSO app automatically with MSBuild.